# git script works when shell = /bin/sh but not when shell = /bin/bash. How to fix

Tags: git, bash, shell

I am using this script (filename git-proj-setup):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d "project1" ]; then
    echo Creating project1 folder
    mkdir "project1"
fi

git clone git@gitserver:CDE/project1
cd ./project1
git checkout master
```

I run the script like this:

```
git proj-setup
```

When I run this script from my shell the program runs as expected:

```
person1@comp1 /c/dev
$ git proj-setup
Creating project1 folder
Cloning into 'project1'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
Receiving objects: 100
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), 275 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

person1@comp1 /c/dev
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

But when I run from another machine, the script fails:

```
person2@comp2 MINGW64 /c/dev
$ git proj-setup
git: 'proj-setup' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

person2@comp2 MINGW64 /c/dev
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/bash
```

But if I run the commands in the script from this second computer it DOES work as expected.

This is running git for Windows on Windows 7.

There is a slight difference in that it works on the PC where the latest Git for windows is installed: https://git-scm.com/download/win version 2.7.0 64 bit version.  On the PC where it doesn't work it is running an earlier version of git.  Not sure if that is relevant.

Is the problem due to the different shell?  How can I get one script to run on both the /bin/sh and also the /bin/bash shell?

Comment: @AngusComber is your git-proj-setup in your $PATH?

Comment: You may have different definitions for git aliases depending on the computer ($HOME/.gitconfig or .git/config).

Comment: That's obviously not related to the shell!

Comment: @TNW That question is key.  Adding on PC2 fixed for PC2.  But the folder not in path on PC1.  Strange.

Comment: Note that `$SHELL` is the login shell, not necessarily the one you are currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only condition to run a command `git xxx` is that:

- the script is named `git-xxx` (no extension)
- said script is in the `PATH`

That is working with an old [git 1.9.5 msysgit-based](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) or the [more recent git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
In both instance, you do not have to be in a git bash: you can run it directly from a regular CMD session.

Double-check if `git-proj-setup` is in one of the folders referenced by the PATH of the other machine.

Comment: your answer is correct because when I added to path on PC2 it worked.  But strange thing is that on my PC the path I ran script from, the current directory (.), is not in my path, but it worked.  Anyway, adding to path fixes.

Comment: @AngusComber Never add `.` to your PATH! Otherwise a hacker who got user-privileges can "overwrite" system commands.